# I want to use matplotlib show a grayscale figure transformed by tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

I am newcomer for TensorFlow 2.0, and after I load a figure, I want to plot the grayscaled figure transformed by tensorflow, unfortunately there was a error came up.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = tf.io.read_file('/home/1.png')
image = tf.image.decode_png(im)
image_gray = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image_gray)
```

Then the error pops:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zhongl/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2677, in imshow
    None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "/home/zhongl/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1599, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "/home/zhongl/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 369, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zhongl/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 369, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zhongl/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5679, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "/home/zhongl/miniconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 690, in set_data
    .format(self._A.shape))
TypeError: Invalid shape (321, 327, 1) for image data
```

But the original transformed figure without any question.

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The important part of your error message is:

> TypeError: Invalid shape (321, 327, 1) for image data

Obviously, TensorFlow's [`rgb_to_grayscale`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale) stores converted images in that way:

> The size of the last dimension of the output is 1, containing the Grayscale value of the pixels.

Nevertheless, Matplotlib can't handle data in that way for grayscale images, but expects a shape like `(321, 327)`, i.e. without single-dimensional data.

Since you're dealing with NumPy arrays here, you can use NumPy's [`squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) method to get rid of the additional dimension:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = tf.io.read_file('/home/1.png')
image = tf.image.decode_png(im)
image_gray = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image).squeeze()   # <-- !

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image_gray)
```

Hope that helps!